# Getting values from dynamic form in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a dynamic form written with the following code and I am trying to get all the details in the form. How can I go about doing it?

Form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('backendProduct/save_product'); ?>
    <div class="row"  ng-app="appcolor">
<div id="gc_photos"></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/template" id="imageTemplate">
    <div class="row gc_photo" id="gc_photo_{{id}}" style=" border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="hidden" name="images[{{id}}][filename]" value="{{filename}}"/>
            <img class="gc_thumbnail" src="<?php echo base_url('../product_images/{{filename}}');?>" style="padding:5px; border:1px solid #ddd"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="images[{{id}}][alt]" value="{{alt}}" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo lang('alt_tag');?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="primary_image" value="{{id}}" {{#primary}}checked="checked"{{/primary}}/> <?php echo lang('main_image');?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a onclick="return remove_image($(this));" rel="{{id}}" class="btn btn-danger pull-right"><i class="icon-times "></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label><?php echo lang('caption');?></label>
                    <textarea name="images[{{id}}][caption]" class="form-control" rows="3">{{caption}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Function

```
function addProductImage(val)
{
    view = {
        id:val.item_id,
        filename:val.detail_image_name,
        alt:val.alt,
        primary:val.primary,
        caption:val.caption
    }

    var output = Mustache.render(imageTemplate, view);

    $('#gc_photos').append(output);
    $('#gc_photos').sortable('refresh');
    photos_sortable();
}
```

Comment: What form? You don't have one from the looks of things, the code above just seems to be displaying a template. If you do have a form, you should post the relevant code.

Comment: What does `trying to get the details` even mean? Please be more specific about what actual issues are

Comment: @Philip the template is displayed in the div name gc_photos.
I have updated the code.

Comment: @charlietfl I am trying to get the details such as image name, value of the checkbox and caption. As the form is dynamic, there could be 1 or more images details shown in the form.

Comment: use `serialize()` to get all the form data in jQuery ...then loop through the arrays with php . Still not clear what issue is ...php or jQeury?